# Configure KafkaListener programmatically in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How can we change the consumption mode to `earliest` for only one consumer. I tried to set the `auto-offset-reset` in the properties but it **does not** work

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${app.kafka.mytopic}'}",
                   groupId = "#{'${app.kafka.group-id}'}",
                   properties = {"auto-offset-reset:earliest"})
public void consumeAllEvents(Event event) {
 
}
```

What's the right to override the kafka config ?

Comment: `properties = {"auto.offset.reset:earliest"}` should work

Comment: But we have to pay attention to the `group-id` !

Comment: Yes. That property only gets used when the group is brand new. Doesn't mean it "doesn't work". Just might not work the way you expected. You need to explicitly seek consumers if you want to always read from beginning

Comment: @OneCricketeer is it possible to seek the consumer using @ KafkaListener ?

Comment: You can, but if you always want to start from the beginning, turn off auto commits

Answer (score 0):

> @OneCricketeer is it possible to seek the consumer using @ KafkaListener ?

Have your listener extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` and call `seekToBeginning()` from `onPartitionsAssigned()`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek

(Scroll down to near the end of that section).